# Proof of an inequality to bound a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality, cauchy-sequences

I have the sequence $v_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{x^k}{k}$, with $\mid x\mid<1$. I'm trying to prove that for $p\geq1$  : $$\mid v_{n+p}-v_n\mid\leq\frac{\mid x\mid^{n+1}}{1-\mid x \mid}$$
What I found, and I'm not sure it's helpful, is that : 
\begin{align}
\mid v_{n+p}-v_n\mid &=\left|\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n+p}\frac{x^k}{k} -\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{x^k}{k} \right|\\
&=\left| \sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{n+p}\frac{x^k}{k}   \right|\\
&\leq \sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{n+p}\frac{\mid x\mid^k}{k}
\end{align}
Each term in the last sum is smaller than $|x|^k$ and there are $p$ terms so the last sum is smaller then $\sum\limits_{k=1}^p|x|^k$
but then again not sure this helps because if you applies the geometric series formula, you still have a $p$ in the answer and not $n+1$. So if anyone could give me a hint on where to start, where to go, but not the full solution I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow on like that

$$\begin{align}
\mid v_{n+p}-v_n\mid &=\left|\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n+p}\frac{x^k}{k} -\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{x^k}{k} \right|\\
&=\left| \sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{n+p}\frac{x^k}{k}   \right|\\
&\leq \sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{n+p}\frac{\mid x\mid^k}{k}\\
&\le \vert x \vert^{n+1}\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{\mid x\mid^{k-n-1}}{k}\\
&\le \vert x \vert^{n+1}\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^\infty\mid x\mid^{k-n-1}\\
&= \vert x \vert^{n+1} \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \vert x \vert^k\\
&= \frac{\vert x \vert^{n+1}}{1-\vert x \vert}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

You have 
$$
\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{n+p}\frac{\lvert x\rvert^k}{k}
\leq \sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{n+p}\lvert x\rvert^k
= \lvert x\rvert^{n+1}\cdot \frac{1-\lvert x\rvert^p}{1-\lvert x\rvert}
$$
Now use that $1-\lvert x\rvert^p \leq 1$.